# Firefoxでプログラムからアドオンを開きたい

Tags: firefox, firefox-webextension

Firefoxでよく使うアドオンがあるのですが、毎回マウスを移動させるのが面倒なのでボタン一発で開けるようにしたいです。

私なりに考えたやり方では（代案があればぜひ！）、
1. ブックマークレット中のJavascriptからアドオンを開く
2. ショートカットを設定してブックマークレットを開くようにする

の2段構えでできると思っています。
ここで質問なのですが、1.のようにJavascriptからアドオンを開くにはどうしたらよいでしょうか？

ご教示いただければ幸いです。ヒント等でも大歓迎です。

Comment: ちょっと挑戦してみた結果なんですが、ムリ……ではないでしょうか。ブックマークレットて`window`がグローバルオブジェクトですよね。で最近のアドオンはWebExtensionですけど、それに用意されてるJavaScript APIにしても拡張機能のドキュメントやボタンのスクリプト用で、通常のページからは使えません。ブックマークレット`javascript:void%20function(){alert(typeof%20browser)}();`は`undefined`を表示します。ここから先はもしAPIが使えた場合の話で、できたとしても拡張機能の情報を取得できるだけでインスタンスが取れないです。ただ`runtime`APIで他の拡張機能と接続してjsonは送れるようですが、相手が受け取り処理を書いてなければ意味ないです。同機能のブックマークレットを書いた方が早いのでは……と思いました

Comment: なるほど。お試しいただきありがとうございます！
ブラウザ内部の仕組みに詳しくないのでご回答をもとに勉強してみます。とりあえず、やりたいことは別の方法を検討してみます。ありがとうございました！